# How can I make changes to "people" page?

Tags: 7

Drupal have a list of users with following link - `my_site/admin/people`
I have some boolean field for every user and I want to show on this page users, who have `true` value of this field.
How can I manipulate the content of `people` page.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this:
enable [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views), this would provide you with a view for "/people" page.

> Replaces administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for
>   superior usability. Filter users by name, ban/blocked status, or user
>   roles.

Use a filter setting boolean field to "true" or expose this filter to allow admins to filter people by "true" or "false"

Answer (score 0):

In drupal7 site /admin/config/people/accounts/fields option is there, you have to add boolean filed and choose type then it will reflect to peoples page.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

On url my_site/admin/config/people/accounts/fields you have the possibility to add extra fields to the user account. If you add the field there it will appear on the people page.